# Configure Postfix with Virtual Mailboxes to forward to a script

Tags: php, mysql, postfix-mta, forwarding

I am using the Postfix MTA with a virtual configuration from MySQL for the Users and Forwardings.
Now I want some Adresses (that are dynamicaly generated, for writing via E-Mail to a Forum) to be forwarded to a php-script.

I already have tried to put the script quoted and piped as destination bit it doesn't work.
"|php -q /path/to/script.php"
But if I send a mail to that domain it says:
User “|php -q /path/to/script.php"@mydomain.tld not found

Comment: Could http://www.phpvs.net/articles/blakes-centos-lamp-server-guide/postfix/ help?

Comment: ....or http://www.bergercity.de/linux/postfix-execute-commands-virtual-domains/