# Creating SMTP Account and Receiving mail using PHP

Tags: php, smtp, procmail

I was wondering if during the time of my User Registration for my site, I can create an SMTP account something like : **username@mydomain.com** for that user using PHP?

And also, some method of receiving/fetching the mails using PHP into my DB so that it can act as a mail client as well?

The closest answer I could find was using something like "procmail" or some service like : "http://www.cloudmailin.com/"

However, is there no other method to do it?

For example, when we send a mail at **someuser@facebook.com** it goes directly to his message box. How is this happening?

Comment: If your server runs postfix + mysqldb users its fairly easy to do the creation of the mailaccounts as for the webmail style system just put squirrelmail or something similar in your platform and hack its login to use your login system (or just leave it as sub login)

Comment: I have no clue what you meant and how did you mean it to be done.. However, I understood the squirrelmail part. But that is exactly what I want to know, how does squirrel mail does it??

Comment: its just a web mail package you setup on your web server just like gmail, hotmail etc are all web based packages.  you still need an email server running under them all though and that is postfix + mysql other wise you'd have to write system config files from PHP which if you already don't understand you'll never ever work out

Comment: This is basically identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069199/configure-postfix-with-virtual-mailboxes-to-forward-to-a-script which is however closed, so I cannot mark this as a duplicate.  You will find some more pointers and a better description of the problem there.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this is to setup your mail server to accept mail to *@yourdomain.com, and forward all incoming messages to your PHP script which will parse each incoming message, update your DB, etc.  For more info on how to set this up, see: http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/